# Соотношение слов ПРАЗДНИК и ПРАЗДНЫЙ

Tags: однокоренные-слова, этимология

Пытался найти проверочное слово для непроизносимой Д в слове *праздник*. Единственным кандидатом на ум пришло словно *празден*. Но ведь слова *праздник* и *праздный* не являются однокоренными, а следовательно для проверки указанный вариант использовать нельзя.

Но ведь по логике слова *праздник* и *праздный* связаны между собой по смыслу или же нет?

Answer (score 2):

Родственные слова ***праздный и праздник*** по смыслу связаны. Праздник - день, свободный от работы.

***Праздный***. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз. (исконно рус. — порожний). Из общеслав. *porzdьnъ суф. производного от той же основы, что и лит. sprúgti «лопаться, трескаться» (и становиться в силу этого пустым). *Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004*

***Праздный***; праздный, **пра́здник**. Ввиду наличия -ра- заимств. из цслав., вместо исконнорусск. поро́жний (см.). *Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973*

***Праздник***. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз. Суф. производное от ***праздный*** «праздничный». Праздник буквально — «день, не занятый делами, свободный от работы». *Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004*

Comment: По словообразованию идёт *праздник* -> *праздничный*. Со словом праздный опять нет одного корня.

Comment: Это однокоренные слова. См.: в [Словаре](http://oldword.ru/)

Answer (score 2):

"Цели нет передо мною:
Сердце пусто, празден ум,
И томит меня тоскою
Однозвучный жизни шум (А.С. Пушкин).

О связи слов по смыслу

У слова праздник можно выделить разные семантические поля.
   (1)  Ядро первого семантического поля определяется  этимологией слова праздник (от слова праздный, то есть ‘незанятый’). Слово праздный в словарях определяется как «незанятый, порожний, свободный, пустой»,  примеры: праздная посуда – ‘пустая’, праздное место - ‘ничьё’.

В этом семаническом поле слово праздник определяется как «время, когда не работают, отдыхают». Праздное время – время, когда нет работы: «В праздный день не работают».

(2)  Второе семантическое поле связано с идеей обязательного застолья.

Answer (score 1):

Как мне на уроках русского языка объясняли, вначале было словосочетание "праздный день", затем появилось слово " праздник". Подобное сокращение наблюдается и в слове "сочельник". Поэтому проверить словом " празден" очень даже целесообразно