ПразДник - словарное слово или проверить словом «день»?
Сын в 5 классе при подборе проверочного слова к слову «празДнично» указывает, что слово словарное, как учит начальная школа. Педагог зачеркивает пояснение и исправляет «День». На просьбы пояснить исправления говорит: «Праздничный день». Ребенок задает вопрос, где здесь однокоренное проверочное слово. В ответ «Праздничный день». Праздник - в орфографическом словаре, следовательно,  все его формы и однокоренные слова тоже словарные. Может есть у кого пояснение?


Если в современном языке слово нельзя проверить, то его следует считать словарным. Выбор букв в непроверяемых словах можно объяснить по этимологии, но это не считается проверкой.

В современном языке существуют слова праздный и праздник. Оба они заимствованы из старославянского языка в XI—XIII веках. Прилагательное праздный (пустой, свободный) представляется первичным по отношению к существительному празднику, которое  образовано с помощью  суффикса ИК. Сравнить: воскресный — воскресник.


Праздный. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз. (исконно рус. — порожний). Из общеслав. *porzdьnъ суф. производного от той же основы, что и лит. sprúgti «лопаться, трескаться» (и становиться в силу этого пустым).
Праздник. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз. Суф. производное от праздный «праздничный». Праздник буквально — «день, не занятый делами, свободный от работы».
Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004
Чередование Ж/ЖД характерно для исконно русских и старославянских слов.

Но современным пользователям языка представляется, что буквы ДН относятся именно к существительному день, хотя по этимологии это не совсем верно. Но в любом случае об обычной проверке слов здесь речи нет, это именно словарное слово.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ
А вот слово праздный можно проверить краткой формой: праздный — празден. И потом СООТНЕСТИ  сочетание праздный день со словом праздник как исторически родственные слова
Это тоже ЭТИМОЛОГИЧЕСКАЯ ПРОВЕРКА,  так как  в современном языке это не родственные  слова. Значение праздный "никем или ничем не заполненный" устарело, и связать эти слова в качестве родственных нельзя.
Тема проверки обсуждалась на форуме
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416580/Соотношение-слов-ПРАЗДНИК-и-ПРАЗДНЫЙ
Большой толковый словарь
ПРАЗДНЫЙ,  1. Ничем не занимающийся, живущий без работы, без дела. Никто не видел его праздным. 2. Не заполненный, не занятый делом, работой. П-ая жизнь. П. ум. П-ые руки. 3. Порождённый бездельем, бесцельный, бесполезный, пустой. П-ая забава. П. разговор. П-ое любопытство. П. вопрос. П-ая болтовня. П. взор (бесцельно устремлённый). 4. Устар. Никем или ничем не заполненный; пустой, порожний. П-ое место. Не найдёшь праздного клочка земли. Праздно, нареч. (1-3 зн.). Жить п. Стоять п. П. взирал на происходящее. Праздность (см.).
ПРАЗДНИК, -а; м. 1. День (дни) торжества, связанного с выдающимся событием, обычаем или общественным деятелем (писателем, учёным, композитором, святым и т.п.).

Можно ли считать слова праздный и праздник родственными в современном языке?. Однозначно нет!  Тогда в слове праздник надо выделить суффикс ИК. И получим: праздник — это праздный человек  или бездельник. Или: праздник  — это праздный, ненужный, пустой  день. Но только не торжественный день

Как проверить непроизносимый согласный?
Для проверки непроизносимого согласного в корне слова необходимо изменить это слово или подобрать однокоренное, чтобы этот согласный оказался перед гласным: вестник (вести), свистнуть (свистеть), яростный (в ярости).
А какой же корень в слове праздник?
Автор ряда словообразовательных и морфемных словарей Александр Николаевич Тихонов слово праздник считал непроизводным и выделял в нём в качестве корня всё слово: праздник/. Слово же праздный, в котором Тихонов выделял корень праздн, он считал ушедшим по значению от слова праздник, и потому не считал эти слова однокоренными.
Если принять точку зрения Тихонова, то подобрать какое-либо слово для проверки Д в слове праздник не получится, и тогда будет прав Ваш сын: слово словарное.
Но не все словаристы согласны с Тихоновым в выделении корня в этом слове. Большинство словаристов  праздник и праздный считают однокоренными и выделяют в них общий корень праздн. Вот как, к примеру, членятся слова с этим корнем в «Школьном словаре строения слов русского языка» З. А. Потихи:



Такая же точка зрения присутствует и в  «Объяснительном русском орфографическом словаре» (авторы - Бешенкова, Иванова, Чельцова), утверждённом к печати Институтом русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН (2015 г.): слово праздник предлагается соотносить со словом праздный, в одной из форм которого Д оказывается перед гласной и отчётливо слышится: празДен.
Если принять такую точку зрения, то слово праздник перестаёт считаться словарным.
Ну а по поводу этимологии слова праздный существуют разные версии…
Из «Объяснительного русского орфографического словаря»:

Есть две версии происхождения этого слова: от порожний со вставкой д или от порожний день.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ. Из комментария в мой адрес в этой теме:

А морфемные словари у множества словаристов мне ни к чему, мне Потихи хватит. У них структурный разбор по составу, который приводит к разногласию с толковым словарем Кузнецова. А я толковые словари в отличие от вас уважаю. Праздн/ик не может быть праздным, бездельным и бесцельным днем, а у слова праздный именно такое (часто негативное) значение.

Я толковые словари тоже уважаю. При этом знаю, что толкования различных слов в разных словарях могут отличаться друг от друга.
Вот как например, трактуются слова праздник и праздный в «Толковом словообразовательном словаре русского языка» И. А. Ширшова (М., 2004):





Пожалуйста, давайте ссылки на все материалы, которые упоминаете: разные этиологические словари, разных словаристов, кроме Тихонова и т. д. Вы отвечаете не только пятикласснику, но и всему форуму. Поэтому желательна полная объективность вашего мнения (без многоточий). // Кто автор орф. объяснительного словаря? У меня есть Глинкина 2009 года, Там все нормально, указан старославянский корень праздъ - свобода, праcлавянский  porzd //   Вот и в Карте слов не выделяется суффикс ИК.

Sharon, много писать сейчас не могу. Один из авторов «Объяснительного русского орфографического словаря» - Ольга Евгеньевна Иванова, главный редактор «Русского орфографического словаря», на который Вы часто ссылаетесь, называя его «лопатинским». Боюсь, что другие фамилии  Вам ничего не скажут.

А мне и не нужны ваши фамилии, вы для форума дайте конкретную информацию: ссылку на орф.словарь и четкая информация из этого словаря, которую вы собираетесь использовать. И желательно без многоточий и намеков, как вы это любите делать. Будьте, пожалуйста, серьезнее и объективнее в своих ответах.  не надо пересказывать разные мнения, но дайте свой обоснованный ответ: родственные слова или нет? И почему так считаете.  // Кстати, откуда разные орф. словари с одинаковым названием, что любопытно (мой 2009 года. г. Владимир и ваш 2015 года), авторы разные. Кто у кого позаимствовал?)

Кстати, я никакого криминала там не вижу. УКазаны старославянская и праславянская основы и перечислены слова, где встречается сочетание ЗДН, только и всего.

Sharon, в отличие от Вас я достаточно строг в передаче информации источников, которыми пользуюсь. Хотел и в этот раз для достоверности сообщения прикрепить фото соответствующего фрагмента из словаря, но почему-то не получилось это сделать, сколько ни пытался. А моё собственное мнение по данному вопросу - слова эти родственны процентов на 50. И согласиться можно при их анализе с округлениями как в большую, так и в меньшую от этих 50 % сторону.

Мне ваш стиль ответов удивляет, пишете советы мамам школьников и самим школьникам, как им разговаривать с учителем. // Фотоколлажи не обязательны, можете кратко записать, что видите. // А по поводу вопроса я уверена, что слова не родственные, это непроизводные слова, образующие разные словообраз. гнезда.  Анализ нужен, а не только описания. Я никогда не вижу вашей обоснованной точки зрения.  Качаетесь, как березка на ветру: 50 на 50.

Морфемный словарь Потихи – НЕ ОБРАЗЕЦ для словообразовательного разбора. Тихонов отказался от выделения суффикса ИК именно потому, что не видит в таком разборе родственных связей между праздник и праздный. Потиха выделяет узнаваемые в языке морфемы,  но при этом  реальное словообразование не учитывает. А если учесть, то получается БЕССМЫСЛИЦА: праздник – ненужный, лишний, а вовсе не торжественный день.

Кстати, словарь Потихи не обязательно фотографировать, он в Сети в прямом доступе.  https://www.booksite.ru/fulltext/1475592/text.pdf   // Происхождение слов нужно смотреть в этимологических  словарях,которые составляют специалисты,  а орф. словарь может только использовать эти материалы. Нужно давать ссылки на первоисточники.  // Большинство словаристов праздник и праздный считают однокоренными и выделяют в них общий корень праздн.  КТО ЖЕ ЭТО?  Про Потиху я уже сказала, кого еще ШКОЛЬНИКАМ надо слушать?  Наше образование в данный момент приоритетным считает единый СТАНДАРТ в базовых науках.

Sharon: «Тихонов отказался от выделения суффикса ИК именно потому, что не видит в таком разборе родственных связей между праздник и праздный». ===
Ну так я же об этом и писал в своём ответе: «Слово же праздный, в котором Тихонов выделял корень праздн, он считал ушедшим по значению от слова праздник, и потому не считал эти слова однокоренными»!

Привет Ширшову! Значит, у нас День Победы, а у него –  свободный от дел, праздник для бездельников.  Нет, для правильного воспитания школьников словарь не подходит. И кто он такой вообще, где биография, отзывы о словаре. Вы бы уж представили нам этого Ивана Андреевича, или как его зовут.  С чего это я должна слушать Ширшова, а не всем известного Кузнецова. Вы уж для школы предлагайте корректную и проверенную информацию

Sharon: «Привет Ширшову! Значит, у нас День Победы, а у него – свободный от дел, праздник для бездельников». === Sharon, научитесь читать внимательнее, тогда найдёте у Ширшова и другие значения для слова праздник! Вы мне напоминаете персонажа из известного анекдота, не желавшего читать чужие книги и отвечавшего так: «Ч. не читатель, ч. писатель!»

А вы научитесь понимать словарные статьи, прежде чем мне сказки и анекдоты рассказывать, оставьте их для себя. Вас спросили про Ширшова: зачем нужен этот словарь школьнику? Кто этот лингвист, как оценивается его словарь. Вы уже забыли, что отвечаете на школьный вопрос , что за манера. Я и без Ширшова вижу негативную окраску слова праздный, и праздник от него образовать нельзя.  Все, дискуссия закончена.

ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ

Можно ли считать слова праздный и праздник родственными в современном языке? Однозначно нет!

Тогда в слове праздник надо выделить суффикс ИК. И получим: праздн/ик — это праздный человек  или бездельник. Или: праздн/ик  — это праздный, ненужный, пустой  день. Но только не торжественный день.

Вот об этом надо подумать тем, кто считает, что здесь два решения: 50 на 50. Эти слова перестали быть родственными, они образуют разные словообразовательные гнезда и имеют разную семантику. Их связывает только история.

Именно такое решение указано в словаре Тихонова.

В словообразовательном словаре современного русского языка О.А.Ульяновой.— М.: «Аделант», 2013., представлен такой разбор.


Серж, во-первых, в этом словаре представлен словообразовательный, а не морфемный разбор слов. А во-вторых… Попробуйте ответить на мой вопрос, заданный здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/481565/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%9E-%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%97%D0%94%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%A7%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%9C%D0%A3

Слава, как видно из примеров, происходит чередование корня: к/ч. Это значит, что ик — это не суффикс, а корень.

Серж, ну почему Вы так уверены, что именно корня, а не основы? Разве суффиксы ик и ич не могут чередоваться друг с другом? Ср.: стар-ик — стар-ич-ок.

Можно, конечно! Но тогда суффикс выделили бы отдельно.

Ответ Грамоты.ру  https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/317003

https://ask.fm/russian/answers/173720419644

«Можно, конечно! Но тогда суффикс выделили бы отдельно. === Господи, Серж! Неужто Вы не видите, что в ЭТОМ словаре не выделен даже словообразующий суффикс в слове по-праздничному? Что уж говорить об исходных (стоящих в начале статей) словах. Кстати, попробуйте с помощью ЭТОГО словаря найти приставку в слове обуть. Думаю, опираясь на этот словарь, сделать у Вас этого не получится, потому что ни в одном из исходных слов не даётся его морфемного строения, показываются (и то с ошибками) морфемы, с помощью которых от исходных образуются производные слова.
