Нужно ли выделять суффикс ИК в слове "праздник"?

Вот на сайте Большой вопрос пользователи дают ответы
Разбираем: праздник
Праздник — основа
Праздн — корень
ик — уменьшительно-ласкательный суффикс
нулевое окончание



Уменьшительно-ласкательный суффикс? Любопытно, но значение суффикса действительно надо указывать.

А это Карта слов: суффикс ИК не выделяется. В словаре Тихонова также суффикс не выделен. А здесь суффикс ИК выделен.

Как-то везде непорядок, а вопрос важный.  Если суффикс не выделяется, то у нас два непроизводных слова: праздный и праздник, которые родственными считать не следует.


Так как же правильно?  Для меня очевидно, что суффикс ИК выделять не нужно, но не все согласны.
Оба эти слова в современном языке считаются непроизводными, у каждого из них свое словообразовательное гнездо. Например, упразднить — это освободить, отменить, никакого отношения  к празднику слово не имеет.

«А это Карта слов: суффикс ИК не выделяется. В словаре Тихонова также суффикс не выделен.» === Так «Карта слов» и не может отличаться от  словаря Тихонова, т. к. она составлена на базе именно этого словаря!

Послушайте, что же вы от меня хотите? Я задаю вопрос, на него никто не отвечает, никто не интересуется.  Пришлось самой отвечать. А Карта слов не всегда соответствует Тихонову, вспомним глагол положить.  А вот двойственная позиция 50 на 50 множит непонимание среди пользователей, которые выделяют суффикс ИК. В Карту не смотрят, Александра Николаевича не уважают, как и вы в своих ответах.

«А Карта слов не всегда соответствует Тихонову, вспомним глагол положить.» === Вспомнил. Ну и… Её что, разве уже исправили? По-моему, в ней до сих пор тихоновский корень полож.

Ответ на вопрос я даю в теме  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/481527/ПразДник-словарное-слово-или-проверить-словом-день
Здесь я могу повторить содержание одного из ответов:
Можно ли считать слова праздный и праздник родственными в современном языке? Однозначно нет!
Тогда в слове праздник надо выделить суффикс ИК. И получим: праздн/ик — это праздный человек или бездельник. Или: праздн/ик — это праздный, ненужный, пустой день. Но только не торжественный день.
Вот об этом надо подумать тем, кто считает, что здесь два решения: 50 на 50. Эти слова перестали быть родственными, они образуют разные словообразовательные гнезда и имеют разную семантику. Их связывает только история.
Именно такое решение указано в словаре Тихонова.

«Именно такое решение указано в словаре Тихонова.» === А какое решение указано в словаре Потихи, на который недавно Вы советовали переходить и который называли одним из основных школьных словарей?

Мы указываем на выделение суффикса ИК в словаре Потихи. Такой разбор соответствует формально-структурному анализу (уж и не помню, который паз я вам это говорю). Потиха не учитывает словобраз. связи. Но в теме родственных слов необходимо это учитывать.
