Какой способ словообразования у наречия ПО-ПРАЗДНИЧНОМУ?
Встретилась в ответах в теме
ПразДник - словарное слово или проверить словом «день»?
ссылка на «Словообразовательный словарь русского языка» О.А. Ульяновой (М.: «Аделант», 2013), изданном в серии БШС (Библиотека школьных словарей):

Чем можно объяснить приводимое в этом словаре образование наречия по-празничному от прилагательного праздничный префиксальным способом (с помощью только приставки по)? Разве здесь не не префиксально-суффиксальный способ должен быть:
праздничн(ый) —> по-праздничн-ому ❓

Префиксально-суффиксальный. А ваш вопрос имеет отношение к предыдущему вопросу?

Суффиксы н, ом.
